# How to check if the flash file stopped with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using `<Embed>` tag to display a flash file .swf, I want to check if the file have stopped loading with the help of js

Answer (score 0):

You can check by this :

```
if (!movie.IsPlaying())
    alert("Movie Stopped");
```